# ¿Como asignar a variables datos leidos de un procedimiento almacenado?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Estoy utilizando C# y Sql Server
Deseo a través de un procedimiento almacenado sacar datos y asignarla a variables que empleare para llenar un formulario.

Entonces necesito ayuda para poder entender como sacar esos datos de la base de datos y asignarla a variables

Ayuda por favor!

Comment: Lectura sugerida: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 y por otro lado, intenta algo... Sin intentos, la probabilidad de obtener una respuesta es baja. "C# sql server stored procedure tutorial" -> punto de partida.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si vas a hacer esto en más que un formulario, probá **Dapper**. Es un micro orm que sin muchas vueltas, te permite traducir tus consultas realizadas a la base de datos a objetos. De esta manera, te ahorrás el trabajo de mapear variable por variable. Además es rápido, potente y versátil.

Por ejemplo:

```
List<ClaseObjeto> resultado = miConexion.Query<ClaseObjeto>("EXEC nombre_store_procedure").ToList();
```

Para más información, te paso la página con la documentación. Es muy clara y sencilla de leer.

https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper

Por otra parte, considerá el comentario de @fredyfx. Es un buen consejo que te va a fortalecer como desarrollador autodidacta.

Saludos.